# remove specific rows or columns from matrix by condition in r

Tags: r

I created a matrix `mat`. The first row contains all 0's.

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,3,4,5), nrow=4)
mat


     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    3
[3,]    0    4
[4,]    1    5
```

What I want to do is to remove the first row, so it becomes 2x3 matrix. I want to do using boolean condition so that it can appy to any situation. 
This can be easily done if that is a dataframe. But I'm not sure how to do it when it is in matrix form. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what about `mat[-1, ]`?

Comment: @LyzandeR   I need a more general approach as stated in the question. thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean more general? If the first row contains zeroes then remove otherwise not? it is not clear.

Comment: @LyzandeR how to apply a boolean condition to do the job. My real data matrix has many rows, some of which contain all 0's

Comment: To do what job? Remove the first row if it contains zeroes?

Comment: remove any row or column that contains 0

Comment: So you don't have nothing...First column contains zeros, as second one...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which`:

```
#will give you the indices of rows
rows <- unique(which(mat == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1])
#will give you the indices of columns
cols <- unique(which(mat == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2])

#then you can do whatever you want
#remove rows
mat[-rows, ]
#remove columns
mat[, -cols]
#remove all
mat[-rows, -cols]
```